# Is E13B MICR font necessary for printing custom designed checks?

Tags: check

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition) states:

> Although compliance with MICR standards is voluntary in the United States, their use with cheques is almost universal.

So it's *voluntary*. I'm wondering if this means you could use a different monospaced font to print the typical MICR info (checking/routing numbers), or if it *must* be one of the 2 standard fonts, either **E13B MICR font** or **CMC-7 font**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Voluntary” in this case means that the government does not enforce the standards. Instead, the banks do.

Checks are scanned by the banks using either optical or magnetic scanners. If you aren’t using the standard MICR font, you will have a problem.